# Refresh page after submit doesn't work

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, refresh

I have a weird problem.

I have multiple forms on one page. After submitting a form I want to refresh the page. The problem is that with my code the page is refreshed but doesn't submit the form. If I delete the refresh bit, form is submitted.

Do I have missed something? Please only look at the refresh bit since the forms work.

```
<form method="post" action="" id="formProduct1">
 <select id="product_1234" class="selectbox">...stuff...</select>     
 <a href="#" class="actionbutton prodorderbtn submit">Order</a>
</form>
<form method="post" action="" id="formProduct2">
 <select id="product_4321" class="selectbox">...stuff...</select>     
 <a href="#" class="actionbutton prodorderbtn submit">Order</a>
</form>
etc....

 <script>
  $('.submit').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var submit = $(this);
    var form = submit.parents('form').first();
    var selected = form.find('option:selected');
    var pvid = selected.val();
    form.attr('action', '/cart/add/' + pvid).submit();

    setTimeout(window.location.reload(), 500);
    return false;

/**** this also doesn't work ******/
        setTimeout(function() {
          window.location.reload();
        }, 500);
        return false;
/**** this also doesn't work ******/
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: if you are wanting to reload the page why add ajax to the form?

Comment: Yes, you've missed more than 'something'; by default, forms follow the `actionURL` when submitted. If you interrupt the process by a refresh/reload the form will not be submitted as the action of submitting the form will be aborted.

Comment: @user3558931: Ok offcourse! setTimeout('history.go(0);',100); return false; seems to do the trick!

Comment: Well you might want to move back to the basics and use the standard behaviour... I don't understand why you use javascript ?

Comment: @Bartdude: because the form is filled with JSON data

Comment: So what ? when you submit it, it doesn't matter how it was filled in the first place (by a script, by a human user, ...) . But anyway I think you're re-inventing the wheel big time if you ask me... good for you if you get it to work, but you have to know your solution is far from clean.

Comment: @Bartdude: Ok, what would be a better/cleaner solution then? I've been struggling with that issue aswell ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I found a quick dirty solution

```
 setTimeout('history.go(0);',100); return false;
```

Comment: This does not refresh or reload the page; it just loads the page from the browser's cache.